# Why is "Building" not a Constructer but "Resource" is?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function Resource(name = "undefined", count= 0) {
  this.name = name;
  this.count= count;
}

function Building(name = "undefined", count= 0, cost= 0) {
  this.name = name;
  this.count= count;
  this.cost= cost;
}

function NewBuilding(name) {
  Building[Buildz] = new Building(name);
  createBuildingBtn(name);
  Buildz++;
}

function NewResource(name) {
  Res[Resz] = new Resource(name);
  createResourceDiv(name);
  Resz++;
}
```

Well i have this Code, and "Building" is nearly exactly the same as Resource is. Resource works, but Building dosnt. Well i hope you can help me.

Comment: Any function that is invoked with the `new` keyword is a constructor.

Comment: What do you mean by "Resource works, but Building dosnt"?

Comment: What is `Building[Buildz]` supposed to be? You have a function called `Building` and an Array called `Building` in the same scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a function called `Building` and an Array called `Building` in the same scope. Change your Array name to something else and it works. `Resource` works because you used a different name for its accompanying array (`Res`).

```js
Builds = [];
Res = []
Buildz = 0;
Resz = 0;

function Resource(name = "undefined", count= 0) {
  this.name = name;
  this.count= count;
}

function Building(name = "undefined", count= 0, cost= 0) {
  this.name = name;
  this.count= count;
  this.cost= cost;
}

function NewBuilding(name) {
  Builds[Buildz] = new Building(name);
  Buildz++;
}

function NewResource(name) {
  Res[Resz] = new Resource(name);
  Resz++;
}

NewBuilding("Test");
NewResource("Test2");

console.log(Builds);
```

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but I would just `push` the new items onto the array instead of  using the *Buildz* and *Resz* counters

Comment: @vogomatix I agree, but I wanted to keep the OPs code as close to original as possible.